# How do I decompose $\sigma = (15243)$ into $\sigma = (12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)(12)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $\sigma = (15243)$. Then two expressions for $\sigma$ as a product of transpositions are

$\sigma = (15)(52)(24)(43)$
and
$\sigma = (12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)(12).$

I am having trouble understanding how one can easily go from $\sigma = (15243)$ to$\sigma = (12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)(12)$.

Comment: "*How can one easily go from...*"  Does it need to be easy?  It sounds like the point the author of whatever passage you are reading is trying to make is that decomposition into products of transpositions does not need to be unique and does not need to involve the same number of transpositions (*though it does need to involve the same* **parity** *of transpositions*).

Comment: I see what you mean. I think the question that I would like answered is how to formulate the process of going from the first cycle to the cycle as a product of 10 transpositions.

Comment: Here's how you can make your own crazy long expression for $\sigma = (15243)$. Start by writing a random very long product of transpositions. Typing randomly with my fingers I get $\tau = (42)(51)(42)(32)(14)(24)(53)(24)(13)(35)(41)(23)(24)(34)(31)(12)(43)$. Next, compute $\rho = \tau^{-1}\sigma$. Next, factor $\rho$ as a product of transpositions. Finally, write $\sigma = \tau\rho$.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I strongly agree with what @JMoravitz states in the comments, if you still need to convince yourself about the equality, you can work backwards: work from $(12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)(12)$ all the way to $(15243)$:

The way you go about doing this is picking a number from $1$ to $5$, and going through the transpositions to see where it ends up. Say we picked $1$.

A transposition $(1\ a)$ sends $1$ to $a$, just like a transposition $(a\ 1)$.

$$\begin{align} (12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)(12)[1] &= (12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)(23)[2] \\
&= (12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)(45)(34)[3]\\
&= (12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)(45)[4] \\
&= (12)(34)(23)(12)(23)(34)[5] \\
&= 5\end{align}$$

Notice I skipped a bunch of steps in the end because in the last transpositions $5$ didn't appear.

In $(15243)$ we also have that $1$ goes to $5$, so we are fine. You can keep doing this if you want for $2, 3, 4$ and $5$.

Another interesting thing would be to find a way of easily turning a permutation into a product of transpositions. There is an easy *algorithm* for that.

Comment: An interesting exercise along these lines: show that any element of $S_5$ can be written *uniquely* as a product $C_{5,a} C_{4,b} C_{3,c} C_{2,d}$ where for example $C_{5,5} = \mathrm{id}$, $C_{5,4} = (5~4)$, $C_{5,3} = (4~3) (5~4)$, $C_{5,2} = (3~2) (4~3) (5~4)$, $C_{5,1} = (2~1) (3~2) (4~3) (5~4)$, and similarly for $C_{4,b}$, etc.